# How to add totals to each group in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I need to have a total for each grouping within a row group in SSRS. Currently, a total is added right at the end of the row group.

So, if I have the following data:

```
TeamName    BusinessSegment  PaymentPeriod  BusinessArea      ProductType        PolicyCount201501    Premium201501   
---------------------------  -------------  ----------------  ----------------   ------------------   --------------- 
Office      Non-property     Monthly        Commercial Lines  Sectional Title    0.00                 0.00            
Office1     Non-property     Annual         Commercial Lines  C&I Generic (Web   1.00                 24025.00        
Office1     Non-property     Annual         Commercial Lines  Property Protect   1.00                 24025.00       
Office1     Non-property     Monthly        Commercial Lines  BizzInsure         1.00                 24025.00      
Office1     Non-property     Monthly        Commercial Lines  Sectional Title    1.00                 24025.00       
Office2     Non-property     Annual         Commercial Lines  Property Protect   1.00                 24025.00        
Office2     Non-property     Annual         Commercial Lines  Sectional Title    1.00                 24025.00        
Office2     Non-property     Annual         Commercial Lines  Sectional Title    1.00                 24025.00        
Office2     Non-property     Monthly        Commercial Lines  M&F Commercial B   1.00                 24025.00        
Office2     Non-property     Monthly        Commercial Lines  Sectional Title    1.00                 24025.00
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Team Name       Business Segment    Payment Period  Business Area       Product Type    Policy Count 201501     Premium 201501
Office          Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Sectional Title 0.00                    0.00
                                                    Total                               0.00                    0.00
                                    Monthly Total                                       0.00                    0.00
                Non-property Total                                                      0.00                    0.00
Office Total                                                                            0.00                    0.00
Office1         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something1      1.00                    1.00
Office1         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               2.00                    2.00
                                    Annual Total                                        2.00                    2.00
Office1         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something1      0.00                    1.00
Office1         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               1.00                    2.00
                                    Monthly Total                                       1.00                    2.00
                Non-property Total                                                      3.00                    4.00
Office1 Total                                                                           3.00                    4.00
Office2         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something1      0.00                    1.00
Office2         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               1.00                    2.00
                                    Annual Total                                        1.00                    2.00
Office2         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something1      2.00                    1.00
Office2         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               3.00                    2.00
                                    Monthly Total                                       3.00                    2.00
                Non-property Total                                                      4.00                    4.00
Office2 Total                                                                           4.00                    4.00
Grand Total                                                                             7.00                    8.00
```

Note that PaymentPeriod is grouped by `Monthly` and `Annually` and there is a total after `Monthly` and a total after `Annually`. 
Currently, the following is rendered (Note the single `Annual` total at the end of each `PaymentPeriod` grouping:

```
Team Name       Business Segment    Payment Period  Business Area       Product Type    Policy Count 201501     Premium 201501
Office          Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Sectional Title 0.00                    0.00
                                                    Total                               0.00                    0.00
                                    Monthly Total                                       0.00                    0.00
                Non-property Total                                                      0.00                    0.00
Office Total                                                                            0.00                    0.00
Office1         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something1      1.00                    1.00
Office1         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               2.00                    2.00
Office1         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something1      0.00                    1.00
Office1         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               1.00                    2.00
                                    Annual Total                                        3.00                    4.00
                Non-property Total                                                      3.00                    4.00
Office1 Total                                                                           3.00                    4.00
Office2         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something1      0.00                    1.00
Office2         Non-property        Annual          Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               1.00                    2.00
Office2         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something1      2.00                    1.00
Office2         Non-property        Monthly         Commercial Lines    Something2      1.00                    1.00
                                                    Total                               3.00                    2.00
                                    Annual Total                                        4.00                    4.00
                Non-property Total                                                      4.00                    4.00
Office2 Total                                                                           4.00                    4.00
Grand Total                                                                             7.00                    8.00
```

How would I achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another child group to your `Payment Period` group and add total to your second group. Delete the column from display for the first group (Do not delete the first group).

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. I've got another question regarding toggling the groupings, but I'll post that as a new question...if you want a squeeze at it p2k.