# How to toggle a SSRS row group above a report item, not below the report item

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I need to toggle a group via a report item. However, the report item is below the group details, thus when the group is toggled, the group details below the toggle item is hidden/shown, and not the group details above the toggle item.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

p2k gave a solution that had an impact on the way the groupings were toggled. Check below

[How to add totals to each group in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282715/how-to-add-totals-to-each-group-in-ssrs/40291957#40291957)

Basically adding a child group to an existing row group resulted in the desired effect of toggling a group above the item, not below it.